# MIPS - Division of 3 floats

Tags: mips, floating-point-precision

One of my first MIPS tasks.
I tried a lot and read a few tutorials but I`m unable to find the failure.
(3.0 + 3.0 + 3.0) 'div' 3.0 gives the result 0.0
Hope you can help me to find my mistake.

```
.text         
.globl  main

main:       
    ##Enter first float:
    la    $a0,prompt1       
    li    $v0,4             
    syscall                 
    li    $v0,6             
    syscall
    move    $s0,$v0
    mtc1    $s0,$f0

    ##Enter second float:   
    la    $a0,prompt1       
    li    $v0,4             
    syscall                 
    li    $v0,6             
    syscall
    move    $s1,$v0
    mtc1    $s1,$f1

    ##Enter third float:      
    la    $a0,prompt1       
    li    $v0,4             
    syscall                 
    li    $v0,6             
    syscall
    move    $s2,$v0
    mtc1    $s2,$f2 

    ##Calculate"((f0+f1+f2) div by 3.0)"
    l.s     $f3, fp1
    add.s   $f0, $f0, $f1
    add.s   $f0, $f0, $f2
    div.s   $f0, $f0, $f3
    mfc1 $s0, $f0 

    la    $a0,prompt2       
    li    $v0,4             
    syscall 

    move  $a0, $s0
    li    $v0,2
    syscall

.data
fp1: .float 3.0
prompt1: .asciiz "Enter a float: "
prompt2: .asciiz "The result is: "
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the syscalls incorrectly.

The description for syscall 6 (`read float`) says: *"**Result** `$f0` contains float read"*.

So after each syscall 6 you can do `mov.s $fn,$f0` (where `$fn` is `$f1`, `$f2`, etc) to copy the float that has been read into one of the other floating-point registers.

---

The description for syscall 2 (`print float`) says: *"**Arguments** `$f12` = float to print"*.
 
So to print the result of the division you could simply place the result in `$f12` (i.e. `div.s $f12, $f0, $f3`) and then use syscall 2.

Answer (score -1):

Thank you very much!
I kept trying and with the help of your hints I finally got it.
Here is the solution (if anyone has similar problems)

```
    .text         
.globl  main

main:       
    ##Enter first float:
        la    $a0,prompt1       
        li    $v0,4             
        syscall                 
        li    $v0,6             
        syscall
    mov.s   $f1, $f0

    ##Enter second float:   
        la    $a0,prompt1       
        li    $v0,4             
        syscall                 
        li    $v0,6             
        syscall
    mov.s   $f2, $f0

    ##Enter third float:      
        la    $a0,prompt1       
        li    $v0,4             
        syscall                 
        li    $v0,6             
        syscall
    mov.s   $f3, $f0

    ##Calculate"((f0+f1+f2) div by 3.0)"
        l.s     $f4, fp1
        add.s   $f1, $f1, $f2
        add.s   $f1, $f1, $f3
        div.s   $f12, $f1, $f4

        la    $a0,prompt2       
        li    $v0,4             
        syscall 

        mfc1    $a0, $f12
        la      $v0,2
        syscall

.data
fp1: .float 3.0
prompt1: .asciiz "Enter a float: "
prompt2: .asciiz "The result is: "
```